# Different answer from different Row Reduced Echelon form for 3x4 Matrix

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

So for my question, I am given a system equation as below:

$$\begin{array}{cccc|c}  
 1 &-1 & 2 & 3 & -2\\  
-3 & 4 & 1 & -6 & 5 \\  
2 & 1 & a^2+9 & a+11 & b \\  
\end{array}$$

And the problem requires me to find all the possible values of $a$ and $b$ such that the system has i) no solutions and ii) has infinietely many solutions with two free variable.

First of all, I tried to reduce the matrix above into the row echelon form using the row operations $R_{2}\to R_{2}+3R_{1}$, $R_{3}\to R_{3}-2R_{1}$, and $R_{3}\to R_{3}-3R_{2}$, which gives me the matrix below:

$$\begin{array}{cccc|c}  
 1 &-1 & 2 & 3 & -2\\  
0 & 1 & 7 & 3 & -1 \\  
0 & 0 & a^2-16 & a-4 & b+7 \\  
\end{array}$$

Using this matrix, I get the answer for  i)  $a=4$ and $b \neq -7$ , ii) $a=4$ and $b\neq7$.

This is because the quadratic $a^2-16$ can give two solutions, either $4$ and $-4$ which leads us to reject the solution of $x=-4$

**However**, I tried to experiment and further reduce this row echelon form using the one more row operation $R_{3}\to R_{3}- \frac{a^2-16}{7} R_{2}$, to get:

$$\begin{array}{cccc|c}  
 1 &-1 & 2 & 3 & -2\\  
0 & 1 & 7 & 3 & -1 \\  
0 & 0 & 0 & a-4-(\frac{a^2-16}{7}*3) & b+7+\frac{a^2-16}{7} \\  
\end{array}$$

I believe that the form above is also a row echelon form, as each pivot is one column to the right of the pivot of the row above. But when solving this quadratic, I get one extra solution, which is $a=-5/3$ from solving the equation $a-4-(\frac{a^2-16}{7}*3)=0$.

This means that the answer for question i) becomes $a=4$ and $b\neq-7$ **and**  $a=-\frac{5}{3} $and $ b\neq\frac{46}{9}$.

How is it possible can I get an extra solution just from using the different row echelon form?

Comment: what happened to your second column entry?

Comment: To emphasize, you performed $R_{3}\to R_{3}- \frac{a^2-16}{7} R_{2}$ but $0 - \frac{a^2-16}{7}$ is not necessarily zero

Comment: I see, I noticed the problem there. Thank you very much!